# How to make the filename as yyyymmdd_hhmmss?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have the following script, but how can i make the %mytimestamp% as 20160929_132659 `yyyymmdd_hhmmss` format?

where i am getting invalid orientation and with comma:

`di29092016_132659,71`

```
set mydate=%date:/=%
set mytime=%time::=%
set mytimestamp=%mydate: =%_%mytime:.=_%

if exist "C:\scan\scan.zip" (
  if exist "\\be\c$\doc\scan.zip" (
    copy C:\scan\scan.zip "\\be\c$\doc\%mytimestamp%scan.zip"
  ) else (
    copy C:\scan\scan.zip "\\be\c$\doc"
  )

)
```

Comment: What are the outputs of `echo %date%` and `echo %time%`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get current datetime on Windows command line, in a suitable format for using in a filename?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-to-get-current-datetime-on-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format-for-us)

Comment: `for /F "tokens=2-7 delims=/:., " %%a in ("%date% %time%") do set mytimestamp=%%c%%b%%a_%%d%%e%%f` If this is not correct, blame my crystal ball that gave me wrong info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this inside your batch file:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7 delims=/:. " %%a in (`echo %DATE% %TIME%`) do set NOW=%%d%%b%%c_%%e%%f%%g
@echo now: %NOW%
```